# OpenCV Image Resize flips dimensions?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm attempting to scale down an image using the Python OpenCV bindings (CV2, the new bindings):

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
print frame.shape
# prints (720, 1280, 3)
smallsize = (146,260)

smallframe = cv2.resize(frame, smallsize)
print smallframe.shape
# prints (260, 146, 3)
```

As you can see, the dimensions somehow end up being flipped on the scaled down image.  Instead of returning an image with dimensions (WxH) **146x260**, I get **260x146**.

What gives?

Comment: Also, it should be noted when I set `smallsize` to (260, 146), everything works out correctly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This was answered long ago but never accepted. Let me explain just a little more for anyone else who gets confused by this. The problem is that in python, OpenCV uses numpy. Numpy array shapes, functions, etc. assume (height, width) while OpenCV functions, methods, etc. use (width, height). You just need to pay attention.

## Summary:

- **`cv2.anything()`** --> use **`(width, height)`**
- **`image.anything()`** --> use **`(height, width)`**
- **`numpy.anything()`** --> use **`(height, width)`**

Comment: Perfect, thank you for explaining.  That makes much more sense now.  Any idea why numpy didn't go with the Width x Height convention?  That seems to be the standard pretty much everywhere...

Comment: @adewinter Well that's a nice surprise that it helped. As for the reason for row-major numpy, I believe it's because matrices usually use that notation and numpy is generally for mathematics, not just images. However since OpenCV is very much about images, it uses the x(column)-major notation.

Comment: Glad to have the explanation, though it makes no sense to me. Using the math conventions of `(rows, cols)` for some functions but `width x height` from the image world just seems bound to muck things up!

Answer (score 2):

Because the size takes the columns first, and the first dimension of the matrix is the rows. Have a look at [the documentation here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize).